# In Judges 8:18 what suggested royalty to Zebah and Zalmunna?

Tags: history, leviticus, judges

> KJV Judges 8:18 Then said he unto Zebah and Zalmunna, What manner of men were they whom ye slew at Tabor? And they answered, **As thou art, so were they; each one resembled the children of a king**.

Should we write this off as pure fawning and flattery? Or are we intended to understand Jews to be particularly royal?

[image: A child of a king]

I'm wondering if it isn't a reference to [the prohibition against cutting off the corners of the beards](http://bible.oremus.org/?passage=Leviticus%2021:5%E2%80%9321:5&version=nrsv). Would Zebah and Zalumunna have made that association? Or any association with beards in general?

Answer (score 2):

Gideon responded by identifying them as his brothers:

> And he replied, “They were my brothers, the sons of my mother; as the Lord lives, if you had saved them alive, I would not kill you.” (Judges 8:19 NRSV)

Gideon takes the noble appearance as a sign that they were his relatives. If all Israelites had a noble appearance, it wouldn't have have that meaning to Gideon.

The connection to having a beard seems strange, because the text doesn't mention anything about Gideon's brothers having had beards. The bible does make at least one connection between the Israelites and royalty (Exodus 19:6), but not in connection with appearance.

Comment: This article seems to suggest that facial hair customs of the time might have been linked to royalty. Mostly though I'm probably grasping at straws: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/2690-beard

Comment: @Ruminator Whether beards were connected to royalty doesn't change the fact that this text has nothing to do with beards. Even so, the article you linked says, "Long beards, as found on later Babylonian and Assyrian sculptures, representing the highest aristocracy, do not, however, seem to have occurred among the Jews."

Comment: So might Gideon (JeruBAAL) et al have adopted the beard style of the king?

Comment: @Ruminator There was no "beard style of the king." "In those days there was no king in Israel" (Judges 21:25). You are conflating Assyria with Israel